# How to load Data Received from google login into my database?

Tags: php, mysql, gmail

I followed the tutorial and done this google login integration.
Logging in Successfull. Displays data in array.
i want to store google-id, name, email, and image path to my database .
it is not storing the details into database.
Please Look into it Once..

Code Is

```html
<?php

########## Google Settings.. Client ID, Client Secret #############
$google_client_id   = '';
$google_client_secret  = '';
$google_redirect_url  = 'http://localhost/googlelogin';
//$google_developer_key  = '';

########## MySql details (Replace with yours) #############
$db_username = "root"; //Database Username
$db_password = ""; //Database Password
$hostname = "localhost"; //Mysql Hostname
$db_name = 'google-login'; //Database Name
###################################################################

//include google api files
require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';

//start session
session_start();

$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setApplicationName('Login to mysite');
$gClient->setClientId($google_client_id);
$gClient->setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
$gClient->setRedirectUri($google_redirect_url);
//$gClient->setDeveloperKey($google_developer_key);

$google_oauthV2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($gClient);

//If user wish to log out, we just unset Session variable
if (isset($_REQUEST['reset'])) 
{
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
  $gClient->revokeToken();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($google_redirect_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}


if (isset($_GET['code'])) 
{ 
 $gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']);
 $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
 header('Location: ' . filter_var($google_redirect_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
 return;
}


if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) 
{ 
  $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}


if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) 
{
   //Get user details if user is logged in
   $user     = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
   $user_id     = $user['id'];
   $user_name    = filter_var($user['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
   $email     = filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  // $profile_url    = filter_var($user['link'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
   $profile_image_url  = filter_var($user['picture'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
   $personMarkup   = "$email<div><img src='$profile_image_url?sz=50'></div>";
   $_SESSION['token']  = $gClient->getAccessToken();
}
else 
{
 //get google login url
 $authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
}

//HTML page start
echo '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
echo '<head>';
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />';
echo '<title>Login with Google</title>';
echo '</head>';
echo '<body>';
echo '<h1>Login with Google</h1>';

if(isset($authUrl)) //user is not logged in, show login button
{
 echo '<a class="login" href="'.$authUrl.'"><img src="images/google-login-button.png" /></a>';
} 
else // user logged in 
{
   /* connect to mysql */
    $connecDB = mysqli_connect($hostname, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name)or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
   
    //compare user id in our database
    $result = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT COUNT(g_id) FROM social_users WHERE g_id= $user_id");
 if($result === false) { 
  die(mysql_error()); //result is false show db error and exit.
 }
 
 $UserCount = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 
    if($UserCount[0]) //user id exist in database
    {
  echo 'Welcome back '.$user_name.'!';
    }else{ //user is new
  
  mysqli_query($connecDB, "INSERT INTO social_users (g_id, g_name, g_email, g_image) 
                    VALUES ('".$user_id."', '" .$user_name."', '" .$email."','".$profile_image_url."')");
        echo 'Hello! '.$user_name.', Thanks for Registering!';
  
 }

 
 echo '<br /><img src="'.$profile_image_url.'?sz=50" /></a>';
 echo '<br /><a class="logout" href="?reset=1">Logout</a>';
 
 //list all user details
 echo '<pre>'; 
 print_r($user);
 echo '</pre>'; 
}
 
echo '</body></html>';
?>
```

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: No error. Logging in correctly. Displaying details properly. only thing is not inserting those 4 records into database.

Comment: may be same user already exists in database

Comment: have you tried debugging to see if $UserCount is being populated?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: after printing $UserCount it shows Array ( [0] => 0 [COUNT(g_id)] => 0 )

Comment: What does it mean.?

Comment: Please any one Answer.